# Error:Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components)or a class/function(for composite components)but got:object

Tags: node.js, json, reactjs, react-native, react-props

```
import React from 'react'

const Newslist=(props)=>{  
    const Items = props.news.map((item)=>{
    return (<h2>{item.title}</h2> )
    });
    return(<div> <Items/> </div>)
}

export default Newslist;
```

This piece of code is not displaying anything in the dom and showing the error

> Error:Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components)or a class/function(for composite components)but got:object

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're rendering `Items` as if it were a React component and not a JSX variable. As the error says, React components can only be created from strings (in the case of HTML elements), classes or functions.  When you render something using the `<JSX/>` syntax it is passed as an argument to `React.createElement`. An array of JSX elements, which is what your `map` call returns, is not one of the accepted parameter types, so you are getting this error. I think this should work:

```
import React from 'react'

const Newslist=(props)=>{  
    const items = props.news.map((item)=>{
    return (<h2>{item.title}</h2> )
    });
    return(<div> {items} </div>)
}

export default Newslist;
```

Comment: Thank you so much Chris. I was stuck at that for a long time.